# Can a Wild Order druid dismiss Wild Shape?

Tags: druid, pathfinder-2e, wild-shape

A Wild Order druid uses the Wild Shape spell to transform into animal form. Can he dismiss it at will? Or does he stay in animal form 'til the duration of spell is over?

I'm a little confused about it because Wild Shape itself says:

> You infuse yourself with primal essence and transform yourself into another form. You can polymorph into any form listed in pest form, which lasts 10 minutes. All other wild shape forms last 1 minute. You can add more forms to your wild shape list with druid feats; your feat might grant you some or all of the forms from a given polymorph spell. When you transform into a form granted by a spell, you gain all the effects of the form you chose from a version of the spell heightened to wild shape's level. Wild shape allows you to use your own shapeshifting training more easily than most polymorph spells. When you choose to use your own attack modifier while polymorphed instead of the form's default attack modifier, you gain a +2 status bonus to your attack rolls.

As you can see there is no mention that spell can be dismissed, unlike Animal Form, for example, that specifically says:

> You call upon primal energy to transform yourself into a Medium animal battle form. When you first cast this spell, choose ape, bear, bull, canine, cat, deer, frog, shark, or snake. You can decide the specific type of animal (such as lion or snow leopard for cat), but this has no effect on the form's Size or statistics. While in this form, you gain the animal trait. **You can Dismiss the spell**.

Also, Wild Shape says that the druid gains **effects of the form**, not "copies the spell and its effects" (which would have included the ability to dismiss the form).

So, this far it looks like in exchange for the benefits of Wild Shape (like attack bonus and such) druids sacrifice their ability to turn it off at will.

But then comes feat Form Control, that says:

> With additional care and effort, you can take on an alternate form for a longer period of time. If your next action is to cast wild shape, wild shape’s spell level is 2 lower than normal (minimum 1st level), but you can remain transformed for up to 1 hour or the listed duration (whichever is longer). **You can still Dismiss the form at any time, as permitted by the spell**.

Which suggests that wild shape can be dismissed, despite no explicit words in Wild Shape allowing it.

Answer (score 3):

### Wild Shape Can Be Dismissed

As you've quoted from Wild Shape:

> When you transform into a form granted by a spell, you gain all the effects of the form you chose from a version of the spell heightened to wild shape's level.

And here's the first section of effects from the spell *pest form*:

> You transform into the battle form of a Tiny animal, such as a cat, insect, lizard, or rat. You can decide the specific type of animal (such as a rat or praying mantis), but this has no effect on the form's Size or statistics. While in this form, you gain the animal trait. **You can Dismiss the spell**.

There's no distinction between the druid "gaining effects of the form" vs "copies the spell and its effects", every piece of the spell's text after the horizontal bar is considered the effect as described under [Reading Spells](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=303).

If there was some spell that Wild Shape allowed gaining the effects from that lacked the "You can Dismiss this spell" piece, then the druid would be stuck in the form as you've suggested. I don't believe there's such a form to date.

Comment: That's the most reasonable answer I've heard this far regarding this question. Though it makes me wonder - why they've used such wording of 'gain effects of the form', not 'copy the spell' or 'effects of the spell'

Comment: @Sarge Paizo's general stance is that they're not going to require their various authors to conform to law-level consistency and that rules should be read in the way that makes the most sense; if two effects say the same thing with different words, they still do the same thing